# vtkOpenGLExtensionManager Extension GL_VERSION_1_2 could not be loaded

Tags: c#, opengl, vtk, volume-rendering

I'm getting this error at runtime when launching my C# volume rendering program.
I saw that I'm not the only one, but still did not find any solution. I read that it could be a NVidia related error. But at first, I coded this program in C++ and everything worked well on that same computer (just different OS)

```
ERROR: In ..\..\..\..\vtksource-prefix\src\vtksource\Rendering\vtkOpenGLExtensionManager.cxx, line 393
vtkOpenGLExtensionManager (1210BD08): Extension GL_VERSION_1_2 could not be loaded.
```

I don't even know what details anyone might need to help me on this, so please ask for precisions if needed.

I saw that for some people, this error does not prevent their program from working. In my case, the rendering is all wrong, so I really need to fix that.

I'm using Kitware VTK Activiz.NET x86. GC: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 860M

Comment: -1, as you don't give enough info. Maybe your GPU fried while you switched OS? Maybe C++ forgot how to handle booleans (*oh wait it can't anyway*). No but really, no idea. Probably the OS just doesn't have drivers supporting that extension.

Comment: Oh, thought you were using VK (as in *Vulkan*). No idea why *GL12* is not supported.

Comment: That's what I said "ask for precisions if needed", I just don't know what to say more. My gpu did not fried, drivers are up to date. However ParaView does not throw this error so I suppose there's a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is working, but I don't really know ***why***

In my device manager, under GPU tab, I have :

```
> Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 860M
```

both of them where enabled, I just disabled the first one and now everything works well.

Does it mean I was never using my GeForce since the beginning?

Comment: The OS should use the one thats probably the right one, iGPU for word, _actual GPU_ for games. Maybe some weird compability; drivers intersecting each other?

Answer (score 2):

I have a nicer solution.
I force NVidia to automatically switch to the dedicated graphic Card when Rendering my application as follows:

[image: Use NVidia Control Center to use external graphic Card for Rendering a Special application]

Comment: @Bart: this is a link to a screenshot hosted at imgur due to the low reputation of OP, he wasn't able to include the image in the answer, it would have been better to edit the post instead to vote for deletion